# mysqli_query result to JSON. How to apply htmlentities()?

Tags: php, json, character-encoding, html-entities

I've got this code that I use to populate a select with an ajax call from another php page:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "SELECT town_name, 
               town_code 
        FROM   tbtown 
        WHERE  area_id = '$id' 
        ORDER BY town_name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Some `town_name` column values, contains characters like `è` `ì` and I found that in those cases the `json_encode()` function set that value to NULL.

I find out also that `htmlentities()` function applied to every array value solve the problem.

I wonder if there is a simple way to apply `htmlentities()`  to the entire array.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Comment: `json_encode('ì')` results in `"\u00ec"` so there must be something else going on. You should fix that instead of trying to patch it up. Take a look at for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: mySql collation was Latin1_Swdish, but also changing it to utf8mb4 values are set to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for this.

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function(&$item, $key) {
    $item = htmlentities($item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ignored the existence of this function!

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```